# reducing code using templated functions

Tags: c++, oop

I have 2 templated functions (overloaded) with similar functionality except for one line of difference in the function body and one extra function argument. 
   Is it possible to combine the functions further to avoid the duplicate code

```
template <class T> int MyClass::function1(string name, T& value)
{
   // same lines
   // if statement
   // statement to execute
   // else
   // different line, calls another function

   return 1;
}

template <class T> int MyClass::function1(string name, T& value,
                                          T defaultValue)
{
   // same lines
   // if statement
   // statement to execute
   // else
   // different line, assign default value to value

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to reduce it to one function only, but you should separate the common code into a third function and give it a proper name. Avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: You can implement the function with lesser arguments in terms of the other by reducing the code duplication.

Comment: How many lines of code does it represent ? If it is just a couple of lines, maybe adding a new function to avoid duplicating them is not worth it ?

Comment: Given a look to current answers I have a question: your 'if' is a run time if or a compile time if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give `defaultValue` a default argument:

```
template <class T> int MyClass::function1(string name, T& value,
                                          T defaultValue = T() )
{
   if (defaultValue == T() )
      //Do something
   else
      //Do something else

   return 1;
}
```

This way you can call the function with either two or three arguments, but the code will be able to tell how many were supplied.  You may need to pick a different value for the default parameter, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T,class Func> int MyClass::function1(string name, T& value, Func fallback)
{
   // same lines
   if (condition) {
       // statement to execute
   } else {
       fallback(value);
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Tweak the functor arguments to taste. And maybe supply a few convenience functors (e.g. one whose constructor takes a value, and when invoked assigns that value to the argument passed in).

If you don't want to change your interface, simply make `function1` a one-line function that invokes this function.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to combine the functions further to avoid the duplicate code

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
// Private function
template <class T> void MyClass<T>::common_function1(string name, T& value)
{
   // same lines
}

// Private function
template <class T> void MyClass<T>::common_function2(string name, T& value)
{
   // statement to execute
}


template <class T> int MyClass<T>::function1(string name, T& value)
{
   common_function1(name, value);
   if ( condition )
     comon_function2(name, value);
   else
   // different line, calls another function

   return 1;
}

template <class T> int MyClass<T>::function1(string name, T& value,
                                          T defaultValue)
{
   common_function1(name, value);
   if ( condition )
     comon_function2(name, value);
   else
   // different line, assign default value to value

   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing it might be:

```
template <class T> bool MyClass::commonfunction(string name, T& value)
{
    // same lines
    // if statement
    // {
    //   statement to execute
    //   return true;
    // }
    // else
    //   return false;
}

template <class T> int MyClass::function1(string name, T& value)
{
    if(!commonfunction(name, value))
    {
        // different line, calls another function
    }

    return 1;
}

template <class T> int MyClass::function1(string name, T& value, T defaultValue)
{
    if(!commonfunction(name, value))
    {
        // different line, assign default value to value
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. 
This is the solution I finally used.

DefaultValue's address is made a default argument (T *). Where defaultValue's address is passed, it is assigned to value parameter. If NULL is passed for default value, another function is called.

```
// declaration
template <class T> int MyClass::function(string name, T& value,    
                                                  T *defaultValue = NULL);
// definition
template <class T> int MyClass::function(string name, T& value,    
                                                  T *defaultValue)
{
  // same lines

  // if statement
  // statement to execute
  // else
  {
     // if default value pointer is passed, assign it to value, else call   
     // another function
     if (defaultValue)
       value = *defaultValue;
     else
       // call another function
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: T - can be bool, int , float, std::string